# independent symmetric 3-valued random variables in Lp

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the following excerpt from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3480):

> Given $1<p<2$, $0<w\leq 1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we fix once and for all a sequence $f_j^{(n)}=f_{p,w,j}^{(n)}$, $1\leq j\leq n$, of independent, symmetric, 3-valued random variables with $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_p}=1$ and $\|f_j^{(n)}\|_{L_2}=\frac{1}{w}$ for $1\leq j\leq n$.  We then define $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ to be the subspace $\text{span}\{f_j^{(n)}:1\leq j\leq n\}$ of $L_p$.  ...  Since the $f_j^{(n)}$ are 3-valued, $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ is a subspace of the span of indicator functions of $3^n$ pairwise disjoint sets.  Thus, we can and will think of $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ as a subspace of $\ell_p^{k_n}$, where $k_n=3^n$.

**Question 1.**  Is there a reference to show that such $f_j^{(n)}$ exist?  I guess we could use something like the Rademacher functions, except 3-valued.  Given any $w\in(0,1]$ and any partition $[0,1]=A\cup B\cup C$ with Lebesgue measures $\lambda(A)=\lambda(C)=\frac{1}{2}w^{2p/(2-p)}$, we can always construct a symmetric 3-valued random variable $r\in L_p$ by letting
\begin{equation*}r(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-w^{-2/(2-p)}&\text{ if }t\in A\\0&\text{ if }t\in B\\w^{-2/(2-p)}&\text{ if }t\in C,\end{array}\right.\end{equation*}
and this satisfies $\|r\|_{L_p}=1$ and $\|r\|_{L_2}=\frac{1}{w}$.  It shouldn't be hard to choose a sequence $(A_j,B_j,C_j)_{j=1}^n$ so that the corresponding sequence $(r_j)_{j=1}^n$ is independent.  However, I would prefer to just cite a reference rather than build them from scratch.

**Question 2.**  I do not understand the last sentence quoted above, about $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ being viewed as a subspace of $\ell_p^{3^n}$.  I get that $F_{p,w}^{(n)}$ is a subspace of the $L_p$-span of characteristic functions on $3^n$ pairwise disjoint subsets of $[0,1]$.  However, why should this span be isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_p^{3^n}$?  Or even just uniformly isomorphic?  (Although, if it is only uniformly isomorphic, then surely the specific constants in the paper must be adjusted to compensate.)

Then, on a somewhat unrelated note:

**Question 3.**  The fact that independent symmetric 3-valued random variables in $L_p$ play such a special role was first (?) discussed by Rosenthal, who seemed to be motivated by the role of independent symmetric 2-valued random variables in $L_p$ in Khintchine's inequality.  It is natural to conjecture that 4-valued ones will also have nice properties.  Has this been studied?